# List NuGet packages from private package repo

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm trying to do what seems like a simple task but running into a wall. I need to get a list of packages from our private NuGet package repo. I then need to later download a specific package based on a user's choice. I have an API key used to access the private repo.

I've tried using both using HTTP commands and nuget.exe directly but am failing with both options. With nuget.exe what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
nuget list -k "MyKey" -source "https://myrepo.com"
```

This doesn't work as `-k` isn't a valid option (though it is inside of `dotnet nuget` for some reason...). The closest is `setApiKey`. So I've tried to do this:

```
nuget setApiKey "MyKey" -source "https://myrepo.com"
nuget list -source "https://myrepo.com" -noninteractive
```

But this doesn't work either. It's not using the API key for whatever reason and failing to authenticate. Any advice on the "right" way to do this?